# How do I answer 'yes' to script error automatically in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

While navigating on a page, sometimes I get a script error from Internet Explorer. I need to say 'yes' every time it appears, otherwise the page doesn't work. How can I make Internet Explorer say 'yes' automatically, i.e. skip the script error warning?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable script errors by opening "Internet Options" and selecting the "Advanced" tab.  On that tab under the "Browsing" section there is an option called "Display a notification about every script error."  Just make sure that one is un checked.

Comment: It isn't equivalent to say 'no' to these error script dialogs, isn't?

Comment: @Jack No it does not tell the IE to stop, in my experience it allows for the rest of the page to continue ignoring whatever errors ocurred in whatever script they occured in. I usually prefer to see everything going on always, but I turn that off as described in the answer, because it gets tiring the quantity of these.

Comment: It's turned off already but I still get these error messages,

Comment: @Jack Try by disabling both of the Script Debugging there too, i think those are off by default though.